# No longer able to login to iOS app via oauth: "the page requested was not found"

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've been unable to login to Facebook via oauth in my iOS app since yesterday (3rd July), instead I'm being redirected to a page stating "the page requested was not found". This is new behaviour -  Usually I'd login through oauth from a  webview (iOS 5.1) without a problem, however now upon attempting to log in I'm redirected to the following page: "The page you requested was not found, Back to previous page", redirected with the following URL-  ttps://m.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=id]&type=external&refid=9&_rdr

This only occurs for returning logins. If the user is authenticating for the first time, agreeing to permissions- in this instance (publish_stream,read_stream), the user can login successfully. If the user then logs out, and attempts to login again, they get the error.

It might be worth noting that the login screen has changed in style as well, to now say "Login to Facebook to connect it to…", while requesting either a username or a phone number,  and no warning if the user enters an incorrect password or username. This differs from earlier behaviour in which the user was informed of an error on the login page.

This also affects the Facebook Hackbook sample application as well-  I can't log into that either.

I've tested this with three fb accounts and It's the same behaviour with each. Is this a bug, or has something changed back end that's causing this behaviour?

Thanks- the app is waiting for review with Apple, so it's a bit troubling!

Edit: This looks like it's been raised with Facebook in the following bug reports, one by me, another by someone who beat me to the punch by an hour or so (someone at Facebook assigned):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/161181664017031?browse=search_4ff5a6a2bf1f51f27060269

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151046355019557?browse=search_4ff5a76b963853613233998

Mine's is the second of the two links; in the event mine isn't a duplicate, I'll leave it's status as new.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by changing the App Type from "Web" to "Native/Desktop"

App Settings -> advanced-> Authentication-> App Type

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was exactly the problem I had with our native app integration. I didn't know to change that setting.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is extremely old, but I had a similar issue which was gone after I did the following:

*developers.facebook.com -> My Apps -> Choose (create) your app -> Status & Review -> turn on the switch*

Perhaps it will help someone.